# Relationship between tables with dates

Tags: ms-access, relationship

I would like to know what kind of relationship I should be making between a dates table and other tables with date fields.

I understand the creation of relationships and tables for normalization purposes. I would just like to better understand relationships where dates are concerned for integrity and querying purposes.

I have a table `tblLog` with dates in more than one field (example: `AuditStart` and `AuditEnd`). I have another table `tblDays` that is just dates.

Would I create a relationship between the date field in `tblDays` and both fields in `tblLog`?

Or would it be better to create a `tblDays1` and `tblDays2` in the relationships and join `AuditStart` to `tblDays1` and `AuditEnd` to `tblDays2`?

Comment: one table, two indexes would be sufficient,   do not forget to make it desc index, if your queries are mostly recent data.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!

If I understand correctly, you mean two joins: 
1) DateID field in tblDays to AuditStart in tblLog
2) DateID field in tblDays to AuditEnd in tblLog

And index descending, got it.

Comment: Why do you even need tblDays?

Comment: @June7 The table has a `WeekID`, a `DayNumW` (1-7), and a `DayNumY` (1-365). It helps when querying by week or weekday.  
I'm mainly concerned with how to handle relationship joins (single occurrence with multiple joins vs multiple occurrences each with a single join) as I would like to understand that better.

Comment: You can use ID or the date itself as long as time part is 00 on both sides. And yes, table would be used twice in query in join to each field. There are 366 days in leap year. So you have this table pre-populated for the next decade or so? WeekID, day of week, day of year can all be calculated. The WeekID would probably be trickiest.

Comment: @June7 Yes the table runs for the next few years to accommodate leap years. The logic was that instead of doing the calculation each time you wanted to group by day of week/day of year, we just built a table with that info already in it. Made doing calculations very simple. But yes, in the relationship window I guess that means having a separate occurrence of `tblDays` for any field in `tblLog` that contains a date.

Comment: If you use date as link then only have to include tblDays in query when you have need of the other fields, which may not always be the case. Whichever way, advise not to set lookup fields in tblLog table.